# Is there a way to create a bilingual/multi-language website using R studio (Rmarkdown) and Github (Github pages)?

Tags: r, github, r-markdown, github-pages

I have look through several questions here and read many blogs on how to create a bilingual/multi-language website through Github. However, none of them created their websites using Rmarkdown in R Studio, so I'm really lost on how, and if is possible, to create a website in different languages (e.g. English and Portuguese) using R and Github?

I already have [website](https://tferreira-araujo.github.io/) in English but I would like to have the option to change the language to Portuguese, so it would also be a relevant site to be used here in Brazil. [Here](https://github.com/tferreira-araujo/tferreira-araujo.github.io) is my repository for creating it, in case someone needs to check to help me out. I created this website following some blogs/videos on how to do it: [Emily blog](https://www.emilyzabor.com/tutorials/rmarkdown_websites_tutorial.html#personal_websites) and [Jules blog](https://jules32.github.io/rmarkdown-website-tutorial/basic_workflow.html).

This is my first time posting here, so please let me know if I'm not providing enough information to solve my problem.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hey Thais, you might find some useful information here: https://gohugo.io/content-management/multilingual/
Boa sorte!

Comment: Just realized that you might not be using the package Blogdown. Here is a nice introduction: https://annielyu.com/2020/01/12/blogdown-website/ .

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same, but unfortunately, didn't come across anything. What I did, since one can not fork twice a source code, I downloaded it as a zip file. After making a few changes (the bilingual/multi-lingual website should have the same tabs as the original one), I pushed it into my GitHub repository, using GitHub app. Finally, I added it to my original English website through _site.YML as a link. (so if your original website is namelastname/github.io/English the bilingual can be namelastname/github.io/Italian. In [site.yml](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/rmarkdown-site.html) you may create an icon to link you the bilingual website.

```
- href: https://namelastname.github.io/Italian/index.html
      icon: fa-globe
```